# When trying to create a calendar control in asp.net in throws a namespace error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

When I am trying to create a calendar control in asp.net it throws me an error called

The 'namespace' attribute cannot contain spaces

The code written is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.png" Height="25px"        Width="25px" />
<cci:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="cal1" PopupbuttonID="img1" TargetControlID="date1" Format="dd/mm/yyyy"></cci:CalendarExtender>
<cci:TextBoxWaterMarkExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="date1" WaterMarkText="Please Select Date To Proceed"></cci:TextBoxWaterMarkExtender>
```

Hoe to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using `ASP.Net MVC` or `ASP.Net WebForms`?

Comment: Can you post the directives you are using to enable `cci` controls on the page (probably `<%@ Import...` or `<%@ Register...`)?

Comment: The directives used are  <%@ Register Assembly ="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cci"  %>